# How to execute Api call in Service Class? -Android MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, service

I'm currently working on a location tracker,
using google API I got location every minute at my service extended LifecycleService class,
now I need to send the location to the server,
and I've send function at ViewModel and repository,
but I'm getting runtime crash with nothing on logcat.

how can i call viewmodel or repository function from service class?

```
private lateinit var viewModel: LocationViewModel

class TrackingService: LifecycleService() {



//THE SEND FUNCTION at Service Class 
     fun sendLocation(latitude: String, longitude: String)
     {
        val mContext: Context= this
        var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
            mContext.getSharedPreferences("UserPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val sharedprefAuthToken = sharedPreferences.getString("authKey","default")
        val recipient = sharedPreferences.getString("ID", null)

        //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Reached here 190", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


        scope.launch {
            //TODO SEND LOCATION REQUEST
            Log.e("sendLocation: ", longitude+latitude.toString() )
            Toast.makeText(mContext, recipient, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            viewModel.sendLoc(sharedprefAuthToken!!, longitude, latitude, recipient!!)

        }
    }
```

ViewModel Class

```
@HiltViewModel
class LocationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val locationRepository: LocationRepository
):ViewModel() {

    private val _sentLocResponse : MutableLiveData<Resource<LocationResponse>> = MutableLiveData()
    val sentLocResponse: LiveData<Resource<LocationResponse>>
        get() = _sentLocResponse

    fun sendLoc(
        authToken: String,
        lon: String,
        lat: String,
        recipient: String
    )=viewModelScope.launch {
        _sentLocResponse.value= locationRepository.sendLocation(authToken, lon, lat, recipient)
    }
}
```

Comment: `I'm getting runtime crash with nothing on logcat` How is this possible? You must be getting a stacktrace of the error in the logcat. Please check again and include the  stacktrace in your question.

Comment: @ArpitShukla kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized

Comment: but i added 
         lateinit var viewModel: LocationViewModel
for initialization

Comment: @SijanNeupane where you init your viewModel object, cause as your error shows it means that viewModel object is not initialised and you're still trying access it's method

Comment: @Bhavin initialized it inside the service class!
where should i initialize it?

Comment: `lateinit` means you are promising the compiler you will initialize the property before it is accessed for the first time. But you never initialized it. Initializing it would look something like `viewModel = LocationViewModel()`. By the way, there is not much point in using a ViewModel in a Service. All the features of ViewModel that you can’t get from a direct subclass of Any are tightly designed around the lifecycles of Activities and Fragments.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i'm using baseFagment for all fragments including locationFragment, and initializing locationViewModel or locationRepository i need to pass the parameters which i dont have like api class!

Comment: @SijanNeupane Can you add your view model and repo code (related to this `viewModel.sendLoc()` call) in the question?

Comment: @ArpitShukla edited! please have a look!

Comment: Looks like you will have to restructure your code a little bit as you can't get the same ViewModel instance that you are using in your Fragment this way. You should inject the `LocationRepository` in your `TrackingService` and call the repository function. And your repository can expose a LiveData (or Flow) which you can then use in you `LocationViewModel`.

Comment: @ArpitShukla  i've followed you on twitter! can you please help me out!

Comment: @SijanNeupane You can post you queries here. I will respond.

Comment: used dagger hilt for repository injection to service! thank you @ArpitShukla for your insight and suggestions!